# How to permanently delete the file from Google Drive, using the Google API Client

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I download and delete files in Google Drive, using the library google-api-php-client. 
To remove, the following functions (File was shared):

```
public function removeFile($fileId) {
    try {
        $this->service->files->delete($fileId);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this case, the web interface Google Drive of the file remains, but to open or move the trash can not be.

How to delete a file, so that it disappeared from the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is bug in Drive SDK. If you can't delete this file just wait, it should disappear later. You can use `trash()`, this will remove file immediately, but it still will be in Drive trash.